# Parsing data from xml and send that data into SQlite database in c#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have to parse xml file and after parsing I have to out related data in sqlite by using c#.
I have parsed the xml file but not able to transfer those data into Sqlite data base.
There are some problem while doing so.
as I am not able to find System.Data.Sqlite even I have installed sqlite.

Thanks...

Comment: Can you tell us what those "problems" are?? Are you getting errors - if so, what are they?? Can you show us a sample XML and the code you use to parse and store that?? You need to give us a bit more information here!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is using the System.Data.Sqlite make sure that you have added sqlite#.dll to your references. In visual studio solution explorer, right click on references -> "add reference" browse and add the appropriate dll. After that you will be able to access the namespace.

Comment: Make sure you download the dll, it's not native to .NET
http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/